# Finding a regular 16-sided polygon whose vertices are lattice points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polygons

Find a regular equilateral and equiangular 16-sided polygon that has vertices that are lattice points.

1. What is the minimum side length?
2. Find the vertices of such a polygon.
3. Find the area of the polygon you found in (2).

I do know that this polygon exists because my teacher said that one did. I have tried to algebraically solve this problem by assigning on vertex to be (a, 0) and math the rest. I also assigned the midpoint of one side to be (a, 0). Neither have worked. It can be any type of lattice.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know if such a figure exists? Why, or why not?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort tends to make a bad impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: Yes, I do know a figure does exist because my teacher clearly said one does. I have tried to find every vertex algebraically by assigning one vertex to be (-a, 0). I think that there is a faster way to do this.

Comment: This is forbidden by the [crystallographic restriction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallographic_restriction_theorem).

Comment: @ChrisCulter It's possible that OP is referring to a different lattice than the canonical one, but they should certainly clarify if that is the case.

Comment: Sorry, if this is a bad question but what exactly is that. I am not sure I completely understand the page you linked.

Comment: @Integrand as far as I know it can be any lattice.

Comment: Lattice points in what lattice? In what dimension?

Comment: @Blue sorry about that I am new and do not know the "protocol." I edited to add my work.

Comment: @Servaes In 2-d

Comment: The ideas in [this animation](https://youtu.be/sDfzCIWpS7Q?t=1074) show that no such polygon exists.

Comment: @Servaes so, it does not matter what type of lattice it is? It will simply never exist?

Comment: Indeed. I have given a sketch of an argument.

Comment: If you go up to sixteen dimensions, you can put the vertices at $(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$, $(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ , $\ldots$,  $(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)$. The result isn't a *planar* polygon, but it *is* equilateral and equiangular.

Comment: @AnonymousPerson: Another "protocol" item. :)  Changing the nature of a question (in this, from seeking a sixteen-sides polygon to an $n$-sided one) is inappropriate, and inconsiderate of those who have answered the original form. I've rolled your question back to its previous version. If you would like to ask about $n$-gons, post a separate question (they're free!); you might link to and from this one to give people more context about your investigations in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will prove that such a polygon cannot exist by contradiction. Let $A_{1}A_{2}...A_{16}$ be such a polygon with the smallest possible side length. Then, consider the construction formed by connecting each vertex to the vertex $3$ sides away (see picture). This construction forms a smaller $16$-gon in the center, titled $B_{1}B_{2}...B_{16}$ (again, see picture). However, note that $B_{1}A_{16}A_{1}A_{2}$ is a parallelogram, so $B_{1}$ is a lattice point, and similarly for $B_{2}$...$B_{16}$. However, this means that $B_{1}B_{2}...B_{16}$ is a lattice $16$-gon with a smaller side length than $A_{1}A_{2}...A_{16}$, contradicting our earlier assumption. Thus, $\boxed{\text{no lattice } 16\text{-gon can exist.}}$

I can only conclude that your math teacher was either mistaken or trying to get you to prove that a lattice $16$-gon cannot exist. By the way, this proof applies to all regular polygons larger than a square.[image]

Comment: Does this argument also work for star-shaped polygons? And for non-square lattices?

Comment: Also, how does 11612  being a parallelogram, make 1 a lattice point?

Comment: Because it is a parallelogram, B1 is the image of A16 under a translation from A1 to A2, making it a lattice point. I suppose this would apply to parallelogram lattices as well because the basic properties of parallelograms still hold. Not sure about star/irregular polygons.

Comment: Also, how is B1 the image of A16 from A1 to A2

Comment: Because the line segments A16A1 and B1A2 are equal in length and parallel

Answer (score 3):

Let $L$ be a lattice and let $v_1,\ldots,v_{16}\in L$ be the vertices of such a regular $16$-sided polygon of minimum side length $m$, in order, so that $|v_{i+1}-v_i|=m$ for all $i$. Because $L$ is a lattice also $v_{i+1}-v_i\in L$, and the points $v_{i+1}-v_i$ together form a regular $16$-sided polygon. The diameter of this polygon is $2m$, so its side length is strictly smaller than $m$, contradicting the minimality of $m$. Hence no such polygon or lattice exists.

This idea is illustrated quite clearly for the regular octagon in [this animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDfzCIWpS7Q&feature=youtu.be&t=1074).

Comment: The diameter is the diameter of the circle around it? Also how is the diameter 2m since m is the side length?

Comment: One way to see this, is to view the points $v_{i+1}-v_i$ as vectors of length $m$, each in a different direction, together forming a regular $16$-gon centered at the origin. So indeed these vertices are all on a circle of radius $m$ centered at the origin.

Comment: But then how is the minimum side length also m?

Comment: Starting from a minimum side length $m$, this construction yields a polygon with a smaller side length, and that's the contradiction. So there is no such polygon of minimal side length. It then follows that there is no such polygon at all, because for any lattice there is a minimum distance between any two points.